# ASP.NET C# How to map a source Id to a Destionation object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I am quite new with automapper and I am trying to map my DTO object to an Entity that should be saved in the DB. Here is my sample code:

```
public class SourceObject {
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Description {get; set;}
 public int StatusId {get; set;}
}

public class DestinationObject {
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Description {get; set;}
 public DestinationStatus Status {get; set;}
}

public DestinationStatus {
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

How can I define a MappingProfile class for AutoMapper that maps the input StatusId property (simple type) of the SourceObject to the DestinationStatus property (object) of the DestinationObject ?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. The best thing you can do here is add a foreign key property for the `Status` reference, so you can then map key to key. EF will do an object-fixup on the reference automatically when you save.

If you can't or won't do that, then your only choice is a custom value resolver, which can be highly inefficient. Essentially, you need to tell AutoMapper that in order to map the id to the reference prop, it needs to use your custom resolver. That custom resolver, then, will take the id and use that to query the database for the object, and then return the object. If you're mapping a list of things, this will cause N queries, one for each item in the list (hence why it's inefficient and not recommended). Also note that the query must be made sync, not async, since the AutoMapper API doesn't support async operations. That could cause issues in certain scenarios where blocking could be a problem.

```
public class StatusResolver : IValueResolver<SourceObject, DestinationObject, DestinationStatus>
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public StatusResolver(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public DestinationStatus Resolve(SourceObject source, DestinationObject destination, int member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return _context.DestinationStatuses.Find(source.StatusId);
    }
}
```

Then

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opts => opts.MapFrom<StatusResolver>())
```